# Register desktop application

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on a desktop application that gives a desktop tray icon notification when a new pull request is created that requires your attention.

I have developed the application entirely using a public access token for my account. Now I have got to the point where other users need to be able to use the application, I am required to implement OAuth 2.0 authentication.

However, VSO's application authentication assumes my application is a web app and asks me for details that I cannot provide (and aren't even relevant).

How can I get an app id so other users can use my application?

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the whole concept. This is the link I am using: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this for now:

> Right now, Visual Studio Team Services only support the web server
>   flow, so there's no supported way to implement OAuth for Visual Studio
>   Team Services from an app like a phone app, since there's no way to
>   securely store the app secret.

As an alternative way, you can use Basic Authentication and ask your users enable "Alternate authentication credentials" and then use the alternative credential to authenticate to VSTS API.

Comment: Thanks. This totally sucks because I can't get user profiles using alternate authentication credentials which my application completely relies on so I'm basically screwed.